# Angular catchError and return observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a model class represents my server response:

```js
class ServerResponse {
  code: number;
  response: string;
}
```

When I call my apis I would like the response to be always `Observable<ServerResponse>`, also when an error occur:

```js
callApi() : Observable<ServerResponse> {

  return this.http.post(this.endpoint, '')
    .pipe(
      // ....
      catchError(err => {
        // ...
        return of(new ServerResponse());
      }
     )
}
```

But I got this typescript error:

`Type 'Observable<Object | ServerResponse>' is not assignable to type Observable<ServerResponse>`

Why do `of` method returns `Observable<Object | ServerResponse>`?

Thanks

Comment: please show me import statement of `of` method

Comment: this is because post method returns an object, you can specify generic type <ServerResponse> as an option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a type to the `post` method:

```js
this.http.post<ServerResponse>(this.endpoint, '')
```

Typescript has no way of inferring the type returned from the `post` if you don't inform it. From the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/client.ts) (among other signatures that you can check there):

```js
  /**
   * Constructs a POST request that interprets the body as a JSON object and returns the full event
   * stream.
   *
   * @param url The endpoint URL.
   * @param body The content to replace with.
   * @param options HTTP options
   *
   * @return An `Observable` of all `HttpEvent`s for the request,
   * with a response body in the requested type.
   */
  post<T>(url: string, body: any|null, options: {
    headers?: HttpHeaders|{[header: string]: string | string[]}, observe: 'events',
    context?: HttpContext,
    params?: HttpParams|
          {[param: string]: string | number | boolean | ReadonlyArray<string|number|boolean>},
    reportProgress?: boolean,
    responseType?: 'json',
    withCredentials?: boolean,
  }): Observable<HttpEvent<T>>;
```